# How to resend data in the event of a timeout jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to send info from a filled out form to a php file which sends mass emails to selected user categories from the form. The problem is that the list is quite large (5000 users) and the operation times out before the list is completely done.

I have set a timeout limit for the operation but I dont know how to resend the original form data back to the php file so that it can continue processing the list. Below is that Jquery Ajax code im using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#subscriberform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit

    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = "'.SITE_PATH.'components/admin/subscribers/ajaxprocess.php";

    $.ajax({
      url: formURL,
      type: "POST",
      data: postData,
      timeout: 30000,
      dataType: "html",
      beforeSend: function(){
        $("#formdata").html("<p>Sending selected articles to subscribers: </p><img src=\"'.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH.'images/ajaxloader.gif\"><p><strong>Please dont close window</strong></p>");
      },
      success: function(data,textStatus){
        $("#formdata").html("<p>Sent Data ["+textStatus+"]: </p>"+data+"");
      },
      error: function(x,t,m){
        // I want to insert the code here
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I am not that knowledgeable in jQuery. Can I please get some assistance on this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "// I want to insert the code here" - what keeps you from doing it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it this way? There's a chance the email will be sent to some users more than once, why not just split the emails into groups of 10 or so? Plus processing 5000 of anything in javascript can be slow in older versions of IE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the `textStatus` for error handler

[from Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

and the value for `textStatus` can be `"timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror"`

```
function doSubmitList(formData)
{
    var formURL = "'.SITE_PATH.'components/admin/subscribers/ajaxprocess.php";

    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        timeout: 30000,
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#formdata").html("<p>Sending selected articles to subscribers: </p><img src=\"'.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH.'images/ajaxloader.gif\"><p><strong>Please dont close window</strong></p>");
        },
        success: function(data,textStatus){
            $("#formdata").html("<p>Sent Data ["+textStatus+"]: </p>"+data+"");
        },
        error: function(x,t,m){
            if(t==="timeout") {
                doSubmitList(formData);
            }
        }
    });
}
```